# sql SELECT query not doing the opposite

Tags: mysql, sql

im using a query that checks for duplicate values, but now i want it to do the opposite of this query:

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE buy_date (SELECT buy_date FROM orders GROUP BY buy_date HAVING count(*)>1)`

Result: [image: result]

I tried changing `HAVING count(*)=0 / HAVING count(*)<1` put it returns nothing

Comment: Edit your question and show your first query.  Also include sample data and desired results.  Note that `COUNT(*)` with `GROUP BY` can never return a value less than 1.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So what would be the opposite of this?

Comment: In SQL you are asking after distinct values. There is a built in function to search for distinct values, appropriately called `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limiting clause `having count(*) < 1` will not return values. You cannot return a recordset with half a row! Try `HAVING count(*) < 2` which will return rows with a count of 1.

You may also want to check out the `DISTINCT` [function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) which returns distinct values.

Comment: Just by changing to `having count(*) <2` it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you consider duplicate two orders with the same buy_date and different id (I suppose id is the name of PK field)

For duplicate - try this:

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM orders o1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'duplicate'
    FROM orders o2
    WHERE o1.id <> o2.id
   AND o1.buy_date = o2.buy_date
)
```

For single - try this:

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM orders o1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'duplicate'
    FROM orders o2
    WHERE o1.id <> o2.id
   AND o1.buy_date = o2.buy_date
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Having Count > 1 returns duplicates as you said.  Having Count = 1 will return non duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be  count(*) = 1?

If you have count(*) = 0 it means that you select only those record that do not exist... so it correctly returns nothing.

Or if you want to be mathematically correct, negation of `sth>1` is `sth<=1`